# Django - To get form.errors as a dictionary instead of HTML code

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Is there a way to get the form errors generated during the django form validation in a dictionary (key as the 'field_name' and value as 'the list of errors relevant to it'), instead of the default HTML code it generates (ul & li combination). I'm not using the generated HTML code, and I'm just bothered about the field name and the errors.

Answer (score 10):

There's not built-in method for return errors as `dict`, but you can use json.

```
form = MyForm(data)
print(form.errors.as_json())
```

[doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.as_json) for `errors.as_json`

Comment: Use `.get_json_data()` to get the dict before serializing

Answer (score 3):

Sure. I use this class often when doing forms that are Ajaxed and I need to return JSON instead. Tweak/improve as necessary. In some cases, you might want to return HTML encoded in the JSON, so I pass in the stripping of HTML tags as an option.

```
from django import forms
from django.template.defaultfilters import striptags

class AjaxBaseForm(forms.BaseForm):
    def errors_as_json(self, strip_tags=False):
        error_summary = {}
        errors = {}
        for error in self.errors.iteritems():
            errors.update({error[0]: unicode(striptags(error[1])
                if strip_tags else error[1])})
        error_summary.update({'errors': errors})
        return error_summary
```

Usage:

```
# forms.py

class MyForm(AjaxBaseForm, forms.Form): # you can also extend ModelForm
    ...

# views.py

def my_view(request):
    form = MyForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
           ...
        else:
            response = form.errors_as_json(strip_tags=True)

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response, ensure_ascii=False),
            content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: In my opinion, it would be simpler to define a custom template tag that takes `form.errors` and renders it into JSON.

Comment: What if you don't have a template to render in? If you're doing any type of ajax response, you won't be able to use a template tag, unless, of course, you're going to render a template as your ajax response, which is, in my opinion inefficient.

Comment: Fair enough, but in that case I'm not sure what you're getting from the mixin as opposed to just calling `json.dumps` on the `form.errors` `ErrorDict` directly in the view.  In the case where you're not stripping tags, it's a verbose way to replicate the behavior of `json.dumps({'errors': form.errors})`.  In the case where you are, `json.dumps({'errors': {field: striptags(errorlist) for field, errorlist in form.errors.iteritems()}})`.

Comment: What you're getting from the mixin is encapsulation. If you have one form, you could put it in the view. But what if you have 5 ajax forms. 10, 20, etc. Putting it into an inherited class encapsulates that functionality and makes testing a lot easier. json.dumps also won't allow you to strip out the HTML embedded in Django's form errors, which the OP asked for.

Comment: I usually think of it as the view's job to handle data formatting.  You could encapsulate the conversion in a utility function, or a view mixin if you're using class-based views.  But I guess design philosophy is a bit off topic for this question.

Comment: Sure, you could move that formatting to a utility function if you were doing that sort of thing in several places to keep the code DRY.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `dict()` worked for me:

```
print(dict(form.errors))
```

I prefer this technique because `as_json()` converts special characters to Unicode escape sequence.

Answer (score 1):

In the view you can do this:

```
f = FooForm(data)
f.errors
```

Comment: This also works in templates.  `form.errors` is an instance of a subclass of `dict` that has special code to render itself as HTML when required, but you can still do all the usual dictionary stuff on it - `{% for fieldname, error_list in form.errors %}` works fine, just for instance.

Answer (score 0):

f.errors.as_json()

Use this method anytime you need to identify an error by its code. This enables things like rewriting the error’s message or writing custom logic in a view when a given error is present. It can also be used to serialize the errors in a custom format (e.g. XML); for instance, as_json() relies on as_data().